# Why can't I install py-setuptools as root in an Alpine 3.9 Docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip, alpine-linux

**The issue is our corporate firewall**

---

Origional question:

When attempting to install `py2-pip` or `py3-pip` in Alpine (Docker), it fails when installing `py-setuptools` with a "Permission denied" error.

I am running this as root.

```
/ # apk add -v py2-pip
(1/1) Installing py-setuptools (40.6.3-r0)
ERROR: py-setuptools-40.6.3-r0: Permission denied
1 error; 42 packages, 313 dirs, 8008 files, 194 MiB
```

This can be reproduced directly:

`docker run -ti alpine sh -c 'apk update && apk add py2-pip'`

```
docker run -ti alpine sh -c 'apk update && apk add py2-pip'
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.9.2-47-ge6bacb23e0 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main]
v3.9.2-46-g5f44785996 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community]
OK: 9758 distinct packages available
(1/12) Installing libbz2 (1.0.6-r6)
(2/12) Installing expat (2.2.6-r0)
(3/12) Installing libffi (3.2.1-r6)
(4/12) Installing gdbm (1.13-r1)
(5/12) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20190105-r0)
(6/12) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20190105-r0)
(7/12) Installing ncurses-libs (6.1_p20190105-r0)
(8/12) Installing readline (7.0.003-r1)
(9/12) Installing sqlite-libs (3.26.0-r3)
(10/12) Installing python2 (2.7.15-r3)
(11/12) Installing py-setuptools (40.6.3-r0)
ERROR: py-setuptools-40.6.3-r0: Permission denied
(12/12) Installing py2-pip (18.1-r0)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
1 error; 62 MiB in 25 packages
```

Seems like it's trying to get to a web resource that returns 403:

```
sendto(7, "GET /alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/py-"..., 67, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 67
sendto(7, "Host: dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org\r\n", 30, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 30
sendto(7, "User-Agent: libfetch/2.0\r\n", 26, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 26
sendto(7, "\r\n", 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 2
setsockopt(7, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
read(7, "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\nDate: Th"..., 1024) = 1024
close(7)                                = 0
wr) = 6
writev(2, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="ERROR: ", iov_len=7}], 2ERROR: ) = 7
writev(2, [{iov_base="py-setuptools-40.6.3-r0: Permiss"..., iov_len=42}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2py
-setuptools-40.6.3-r0: Permission denied) = 42
```

Comment: would you like to share your dockerfile with us?

Comment: @Efrat Sure, but it doesn't matter. I can reproduce this directly: `docker run -ti alpine sh -c 'apk update && apk add py2-pip'` causes the same error, it fails when trying to install `py-setuptools`.

Comment: @RyanFisher did you really tested that? I cannot reproduce with an `alpine` I can reproduce with the jenkins image though

Comment: Ah, well actually no, I can't either: `docker run -ti --user=root jenkins/jenkins:2.169-alpine sh -c 'apk update &&  apk add -v py2-pip'` works like a charm

Comment: Based on your `403` status, either it was a temporal issue in alpine's apk repository, either you are behind a proxy, maybe?

Comment: `docker run -ti alpine sh -c 'apk update && apk add py2-pip'` went very well for me. what am i missing?

Comment: @b.enoit.be yeah, I did. But I just tried it again from my hotspot (not the corp net) and it worked. I think I must be running into a firewall issue. Thanks for letting me know that it worked for you.

Comment: @RyanFisher then yes. You, Efrat and me testing it and getting it working is definitly pointing at something in your corporate network causing that.

Comment: I've tested it too with no problems whatsoever